# JSONKit (in RestKit) converting JSON into NSArray

Tags: ios, json, restkit

I'm using RestKit for HTTP requests, and with some request, I get JSON response with some busses:

```
[{"bus_number":"1","created_at":"2011-08-15T23:07:52Z","id":1,"model":"Setra","registar_number":"123456","seats":50,"tour_id":1,"updated_at":"2011-08-15T23:07:52Z"},{"bus_number":"2","created_at":"2011-08-15T23:07:52Z","id":2,"model":"Mercedes","registar_number":"2234","seats":60,"tour_id":1,"updated_at":"2011-08-15T23:07:52Z"}]
```

I'm getting it into method:

```
- (void)request:(RKRequest*)request didLoadResponse:(RKResponse*)response {  
    NSLog(@"%@", [response bodyAsString]);
}
```

Becouse, I have multiple busses in this JSON, how can I easily parse/decode or whathever do to convert this into NSArray or something for easily accesing into elements?

**EDIT:** I need code sample how to do this with JSONKit, who is already implemented in RESTKit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[json-framework](https://github.com/stig/json-framework/) is one of many third-party libraries you can use to parse JSON.

Comment: JSONKit is already implemented in RestKit, this is why I need code example with JSONKit